# Ruby. Взаимодействие с yandex kassa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, криптография, openssl, яндекс-касса

Не знаю, насколько по теме задавать такие вопросы на подобном ресурсе, но я уже отчаялся.

Никак не получается сформировать верный запрос к серверу яндекс денег (3-й шаг) https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/payment-solution/payout/format-docpage/

Техподдержка ничего толкового не говорит, отмахиваясь ссылками на библиотеки для работы с вводом, а не выводом средств.

Может быть кто-то уже работал с этой системой и может поделиться примером кода?

Answer (score 4):

На всякий случай пишу здесь решение.

Проблема не в коде, проблема не в программистах. Проблема в менеджерах Яндекса.
Запомните, помимо того, что менеджер ОБЯЗАН выдать вам два сертификата, один для шифрования ваших запросов, один для расшифровки ответов Яндекса, обязательно убедись что для расшифровки на стадии тестирования они выдали вам сертификат для ТЕСТОВОГО сервера, а не продакшен варианта. Если они этого не сделали, пинайте их(звонками, именно звонками, email сообщения для этого не годятся) до тех пор пока они всё вам не передадут, продолжайте пинать, даже если они пытаются говорить, что всё необходимо вам передали.

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите материал по ссылке, быть может это поможет (если еще актуально) - https://gist.github.com/kryzhovnik/5b73c1c0637e47b01eaa